# PHP stdClass() with __get() Magic Method

Tags: php, object, singleton, stdclass

Take the following code as an example:

```
class xpto
{
    public function __get($key)
    {
        return $key;
    }
}

function xpto()
{
    static $instance = null;

    if (is_null($instance) === true)
    {
        $instance = new xpto();
    }

    return $instance;
}

echo xpto()->haha; // returns "haha"
```

Now, I'm trying to archive the same result but without have to write the xpto class. My guess is I should have to write something like this:

```
function xpto()
{
    static $instance = null;

    if (is_null($instance) === true)
    {
        $instance = new stdClass();
    }

    return $instance;
}

echo xpto()->haha; // doesn't work - obviously
```

Now, is it possible to add __get() magic functionality to the stdClass object? I guess not, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible. You cannot add anything to stdClass. Also, unlike Java, where every object is a direct or indirect subclass of Object, this is not the case in PHP.

```
class A {};

$a = new A();

var_dump($a instanceof stdClass); // will return false
```

What are you really trying to achieve? Your question sounds a bit like "I want to close the door of my car, but without having a car" :-).

Comment: Thanks Cassy, I thought there might be an obscure way to create some sort of lambda classes but I guess not. Thank you for your input. =)

Answer (score 3):

The OP looks like they are trying to achieve a singleton pattern using a function in the global scope which is probably not the correct way to go, but anyway, regarding Cassy's answer, "You cannot add anything to stdClass" - this is not true.

You can add properties to the stdClass simply by assigning a value to them:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->myProp = 'Hello Property';  // Adds the public property 'myProp'
echo $obj->myProp;
```

<del>However, I think you need PHP 5.3+ in order to add methods (anonymous functions / closures), in which case you might be able to do something like the following. However, I've not tried this. But if this does work, can you do the same with the magic __get() method?</del>

**UPDATE:** As noted in the comments, you cannot dynamically add methods in this way. Assigning an [anonymous function](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (PHP 5.3+) does just that and simply assigns a *function* (strictly a [closure object](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php)) to a public property.

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->myMethod = function($name) {echo 'Hello '.$name;};

// Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::myMethod()
//$obj->myMethod('World');

$m = $obj->myMethod;
$m('World');  // Output: Hello World

call_user_func($obj->myMethod,'Foo');  // Output: Hello Foo
```

Comment: This doesn't work as described, and no, you can't do the same with `__get`. It's not a method you're attaching, it's a function. http://codepad.viper-7.com/nn4h0J

Comment: I confirm this does work but as noted the method is a property and has to be used as such.